# Method inside union type loses it's type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have a union type:

**Edit**: misleading type, below is an actual type

```
type Config<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
       key: K;
       format: (val: T[K]) => unknown
    }
}[keyof T];

declare function defineConfig<T>(config: Config<T>): Config<T>;
```

And it works well, if every values inside an object is a primitive, but if one of the values is object, type safety fails and I get an error (`Parameter 'val' implicitly has an 'any' type`).

Examples:

```
// works well with every `key`
defineConfig<{ foo: string; bar: number; buz: boolean }>({
   key: 'bar',
   format: (val) => `${val}%`
});


// type check fails
defineConfig<{ foo: string; bar: { buz: number; } }>({
   key: 'bar',
   format: (val) => `${val.buz}%`
});


// type check also fails
defineConfig<{ foo: string; bar: { buz: number; } }>({
   key: 'foo',
   format: (val) => `${val}%`
});
```

I am using vscode with tsc.

**Edit:**
I have found that I missed the most important part describing the issue. My apologies! I wrote my actual types in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitReturns=false&noUnusedLocals=true&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&experimentalDecorators=false&emitDecoratorMetadata=false&target=3&jsx=0&strict=true&ts=4.3.0-beta&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmAeAKgPigXigG8AoKcqAbQGkoUEoBrCEOJKLAXQC5iyKKzEL2oBufgKihIAfl4ByAMYBXAM7A4AW3lQAPlHmbEwABbzxk8kjgAnTQENgcqAAoAbvYA2vLDU4BKAjxlBEYEOAB3BAsKAF8SWMohNg5OcRJpaHhkdBg1DU0CPkEWXnUbejQYqXAIBRV1LXMEkhIkEMVgFEQoABMIVAQIbNRMXBdFRFHeEfRsPH1ZtDzGzUDSChsIYGUbBkmcqpaSAHoTqAjbZl6LiE9PC5RTKAg3CBsQKAADIS+AGigACNlMAoOEInRQb04BBVAhgCR+oNhlM5kQoNY4GVgBUEFUgfYbLwEMpNID3qIgcoAF68QFwOCeCD2BixHAuDbkIQKQGE+R-CTWOyOXjuLyBfB4L4AEiIHk8sQApF8Ev50qdzpkoIoTBBFIwMfYUJ5VIiBvQUYcMOjMdjcfjeUTiFTaWDSeSbJTYlA2RyJNyDI7+YLbA5gKL5RKpbL5QA6YHUpUq2Jq1oamqQbW6-VQLyqOCG42mpEWpbWjEMu2VSmO3johPE90Un0+9mcpilAyY4MUIVhiPioLfGNeJOq8RAA):

```
type Config<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
       key: K;
       type?: 'custom' | 'month';
       format?: (val: T[K]) => unknown;
    }
}[keyof T];

type ConfigCustom = {
   key: string;
   type: 'custom';
}

function defineConfig<T>(config: Config<T> | ConfigCustom) {
   return config;
}
```

I wrote `ConfigCustom` to have an easy way out, but it breaks the whole type. Can I make it work somehow?

Comment: I dont see typechecking fails. Every `val` argument is typed

Comment: It works for me in playground too, but inside my project it fails. I guess it has something to do with my tsconfig?

If anyone has a thought what it __might__ be, I would appreciate the insight. At the meantime I'm debugging my config.

Comment: Please show you tsconfig and paste the exact type error that you are getting. If possible, configure the playground according to your tsconfig.

Comment: share your ` defineConfig`

Comment: My most apologies for wasting your time! I forgot that this is not the only type. I have added additional information and link to playground inside the answer.

Comment: How is it supposed to determine the difference between `Config` and `ConfigCustom`?

Comment: My idea was using `type` as `const custom`, to determinate the difference

Comment: I thought if I remove `custom` from type in `Config`, it would work, but it still doesn't. If I implicitly say `type: undefined`, it starts working. Can I omit it somehow?

Comment: But then you should provide `custom` as a function parameter of explicit generic

Comment: @captain-yossarian I didn't get what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Every type in the union contains `custom`. `type?: 'custom' | 'month';` Could you please describe the purpose of custom? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have typesafe definition for every object, that contains a `key` that is of type `keyof T`. But I also need to loose it by providing `custom` values inside `type` - because in this case I will not be getting values from `key` attribute.

Comment: If this is such a hustle, I can just have a `custom` attribute as in `custom: true`.